# How to deal with authentication issue combining the Reactapp and Identity Server4

Tags: reactjs, authentication, oauth, identityserver4

> ***My OAuth Server implemented using Identity Server4;  The issue is I can able to access the Client-2 app after authenticated Client-1 app
> alone.***

I have two react apps and server apps (Reactapp-1, Reactapp-2, Serverapp-1, Serverapp-2).
I am following implicit Grant flow for OAuth Authentication.
This is my Reactapp-1 Singin Configuration

```
import {UserManager}  from "oidc-client";

    var config = {
      authority: "https://localhost:4000/",
      client_id: "ClientOne",
      redirect_uri:  "http://localhost:3000/DataPage/",
      response_type: "id_token token",
      scope: "openid profile server1.read"
  };
    var userManager =  new UserManager(config);
    userManager.signinRedirect();
```

After trigger the above functionality I got landed in the OAuth Login Page. After successful validation of user credentials I have redirected back to the Reactapp-1 data Page with access token.
I can able to make the API call for the Serverapp-1 with received access token.

I have another Reactapp-2 with following config code

```
    var config = {
        authority: "https://localhost:4000/",
        client_id: "ClientTwo",
        redirect_uri:  "http://localhost:3005/DataPage/",
        response_type: "id_token token",
        scope: "openid profile Sever2.read"
      };
    var userManager =  new UserManager(config);
    userManager.signinRedirect();
```

*The major issue is when I trigger this block of code it should prompt the OAuth Login Page. Instead it was simply authenticated the "ClientTwo" configuration and redirecting back to Reactapp-2 with access token has claims belong to the "ClientTwo" (Expected) and User claims belongs to the user who authenticated against "ClientOne".*

**Note**: After authentication done for the Reactapp-1 the cookies set in the browser for the "localhost" domain; I can find the same cookies when make the request for the Reactapp-2.

[image]

[image]

This my .Net core Cookie configuration code:

```
services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>(o =>
{
    o.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
    o.Password.RequireDigit = false;
    o.Password.RequiredLength = 4;
    o.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
})
.AddEntityFrameworkStores<AuthDbContext>()
.AddDefaultTokenProviders();

services.AddIdentityServer()
.AddAspNetIdentity<IdentityUser>()
.AddClientStore<ClientStore>()
.AddResourceStore<ResourceStore>()
.AddDeveloperSigningCredential();

services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(o =>
{
    o.Cookie.Name = "IdentityServer.OAuthCookie";
    o.LoginPath = "/Auth/Login";
    o.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
    o.Cookie.Path = "/";
});

services.AddCors(o =>
{
    o.AddPolicy("AllowAll", o =>
    {
        o.WithOrigins("http://localhost:3005", "http://localhost:3000")
        .AllowAnyHeader()
        .AllowAnyMethod();

    });
});
```

Comment: In general you should use HTTPS everywhere, because cookies might not always be included as you expect when you use HTTP and openid connect. I did blog about that here https://nestenius.se/2023/10/09/debugging-cookie-problems/